# How do I effectively click on an HtmlCell using Java/HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

If you go to
https://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/Pages/WebForm1.aspx?p=1&apn=205-27-014
view page source and search for grdCPhist in the page source, you won't find it.

But, if you click on Taxes, then click on the CP in the 7th column of the 5th row, THEN view page source, you will find a grdCPhist. There is a table with id="grdCPhist".

I want to access that table from Java code using HtmlUnit.

For that, I developed the program below:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClickOnCell {

    public static void ClickOnCell () {
        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
            System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
            webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());
            webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/Pages/WebForm1.aspx?p=1&apn=205-27-014");
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
            page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());
            HtmlTable grdTaxHistory = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("grdTaxHistory");
            HtmlTableDataCell cpCell = (HtmlTableDataCell) grdTaxHistory.getCellAt(4,6);
            System.out.println("cpCell.getTextContent() = " + cpCell.getTextContent());
            cpCell.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000000000);
            page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
            HtmlTable grdCPHistory = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("grdCPhist");
            System.out.println("grdCPHistory = " + grdCPHistory);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("validParcelIDs.txt");
        ClickOnCell();
    }

}
```

I compiled and ran the program using the following two commands:

```
javac -classpath ".:/opt/htmlunit_2.69.0/*" ClickOnCell.java
java -classpath ".:/opt/htmlunit_2.69.0/*" ClickOnCell
```

The program compiled fine. No errors or warnings. However, when I ran the program, I got the following output to the screen:

```
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Jan 13, 2023 5:51:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Jan 13, 2023 5:51:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Jan 13, 2023 5:51:30 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Jan 13, 2023 5:51:30 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Jan 13, 2023 5:51:30 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
cpCell.getTextContent() =                                                                     
                                         CP
                                            
grdCPHistory = null
```

What I am unhappy about in the above is the grdCPHistory table being equal to null. That tells me that HtmlUnit was unable to find the table with id="grdCPhist", as if I hadn't put cpCell.click(); in the code.

How do I change the above code to be able to access, from my Java program, the table with id="grdCPhist"?

Since StackOverflow doesn't allow me to thank you after you suggest to me what to try, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the cell has no effect because the action is triggered from the including anchor.

```
<td align="right">                                                                    
    <a onclick="$('#');" id="grdTaxHistory_lnkViewPayments_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('grdTaxHistory$ctl06$lnkViewPayments','')">$2948.15</a>
</td>
```

You have to select the anchor and click on it.

```
    String url = "http://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/Pages/WebForm1.aspx?p=1&apn=205-27-014";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX)) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

        // don't disable logging if your are hunting for problems
        webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1_000);
        page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();

        // System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        // System.out.println(page.asNormalizedText());
        // System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");


        // no need to click - the table is already there, only not visible

        // page.getAnchorByText("Taxes").click();
        // webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1_000);
        // page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();

        // System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        // System.out.println(page.asNormalizedText());
        // System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");


        HtmlTable grdTaxHistory = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("grdTaxHistory");
        HtmlTableDataCell cpCell = (HtmlTableDataCell) grdTaxHistory.getCellAt(4,6);
        // System.out.println("cpCell.getTextContent() = " + cpCell.getTextContent().trim());

        // the action is triggered by the anchor inside the cell
        // todo this is a hack - make finding the enclosing anchor more robust
        ((HtmlAnchor) cpCell.getFirstChild().getNextSibling()).click();

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1_000);
        page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();

        HtmlTable grdCPHistory = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("grdCPhist");

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(grdCPHistory.asNormalizedText());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
    }
```